# D7 -> D10 upgrade login model with php

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I'm currently working on migrating my Drupal site from D7 to D10 and need help with the on-page token authentication system.

My site uses an interconnection system with other Drupal sites using a user attribute containing a JSON token that is generated upon login. This system provides a token to use in the URL to authenticate users to my site from any page. However, this only works on paths configured in the settings page.

The problem is that the application model changed between D7 and D10 from a procedural model to OOP, and I couldn't get similar code to work on D10.

On my D7 site, I am using the following PHP code to automate multi-site login from a JSON token that is POST from page to page and site to site:

```php
<?php
if (isset($_POST['TOKEN'])){ $token= $_POST['TOKEN']; }
if($uid = user_authenticate($token)){
      $user_obj = user_load_by_token($token);
      $form_state = array();
      $form_state['uid'] = $user_obj->uid;
      user_login_submit(array(), $form_state);
      $base_url=$base_url.'content/mycontent';
}
drupal_goto($base_url);
?>
```

Do you expect to help me find a solution to make similar code work on Drupal 10?

Thanks in advance.